# Merge two braided river layers

Tags: qgis

[image]I have created a braided rivers shapefile (vector layer) extracting the vectors from an existing vector layer using the unique values (names of the rivers) and being a braided river environment the resulting layer is messy showing several braided channels of the river and not one consistent channel the entire length of the river. I have loaded in a rivers polygon layer and includes all of the braided rivers I want but also includes meandering channels that I do not want. Is it possible to intersect the two layers so the output includes the braided channels and the rivers polygon layer of only the rivers I want?

I have converted the rivers polygon layers to lines and tried to intersect the braided rivers and rivers line layers but had no luck - I have attached an image of what I am trying to achieve - I want a consistent channel only where the blue intersects the orange, and to get rid of the remaining orange.

[image]

Comment: @user2856 (added an image to the original post) the first image (blue lines) is the shapefile that I have created that has all of the braided rivers I want in my output (as you can see majority of the lines aren't intersecting) the second image is the rivers polygon layer that I want to select only my braided rivers from (it contains all types of rivers currently) and the last image is how I want my output to look as one layer.

Comment: Your comment implies three images but there are currently only two in the question above?